How do I update the lead conversion screen in Salesforce so required information can be completed?
In Salesforce, I have set required fields on the Opportunity record and Account record:
Account: Billing Address, Type, Website, Number of Employees, Industry
Opportunity: TCV, Term, Type, Lead Source, Need, Timeline, Use Case, Next Steps, Close Date, Stage
These rules work fine when creating an Account or Opportunity from their respective objects, but when I go to convert a lead it prevents the conversion.
How do I update the lead conversion page to allow Sales Reps to fill out this information before converting the lead?
I'm a relatively new Salesforce admin so appreciate the help! Thank you in advance!
Screenshot of lead convert page w/ error
I've reached out to Salesforce Support but they haven't been able to provide a recommended solution. The only thing that has worked is turning off the validation rules (the Account rules are off currently) but that just leads to poor data hygiene, the original issue I was trying to solve.
